# I am getting an error Unable to open 'cygwin.S'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am getting the an cygwin.S error whole error is described below but it occurs when I try to debug the code and debugger goes to line create an array and my code runs perfectly fine on online ide. I can't understand what's the problem. Please tell what other information you need regarding this post and I will update the question according to it.

code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int s;
    cin >> s;
    int ar[s];
}
```

input

3

Error - { Unable to open 'cygwin.S': Unable to read file '\home\keith\builds\mingw\src\gcc-9.2.0\libgcc\config\i386\cygwin.S' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file '\home\keith\builds\mingw\src\gcc-9.2.0\libgcc\config\i386\cygwin.S'). }

Comment: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: and just a little less important: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: You can check if there are updates for gcc package (and if you have all needed components) using cygwin setup. If update doesn't help, the hammer solution would be to reinstall cygwin.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I installed cygwin setup but it didn't help